# Where can I get SQL for default Oracle's "HR" schema?

Tags: oracle

I'm studying Oracle database and have to do some exercises with default "HR" schema. But I think that data in my tables is changed from default values (many students have access to DB and may be someone changed data). Where can I get SQL to construct default "HR" schema?

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Oracle 10g release 2. Also I found sql for 8i sample schemas (http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/obe1013jdev/common/obeconnection.htm#t1s2). Is there any difference?

Comment: "Is there any difference?". Hopefully SCOTT's salary has increased over the years. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

check here the schema is in a zip file

http://code.google.com/p/adf-samples-demos/downloads/detail?name=demoscripts.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to update this post that the above link won't work:

Try this instead:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/sample-models-scripts-224531.html

And refer this also:
http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/jdev/obe11jdev/11/common/connection11g.htm#t1

Hope this helps!!

Comment: To save anyone from wasting their time, the first link is the schema only, no data, which is not helpful since most times these schemas are used with sample apps. The second link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

If practicing using HR Schema is your requirement, you can use the Oracle Live SQL. It has the HR Schema for you to play around with.

https://livesql.oracle.com

Comment: its good but it's only Read only.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but high Google page rank, so here goes:

They are hosted by Oracle on Github now (as of 2018):
https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14198/installation.htm#sthref33

It's under `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/human_resources`

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't access to filesystem on server.

Comment: Is this schema normalized? I wondered because in table JOB_HISTORY it seems like DEPARTMENT_ID only depends on EMPLOYEE_ID, and since EMPLOYEE_ID is only part of the key (EMPLOYEE_ID, START_DATE), it's not in 2NF, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a database connected via SQL developer and could not find HR schema. I wanted to create the HR schema using SQL queries. I used below scripts one by one and create the schema with the SYS user:

Check here: https://support.dbagenesis.com/knowledge-base/script-to-create-hr-schema/

Comment: Rather of linking to outside resources (which may break and make your solution useless for others), it would be more helpful to instead post the scripts/solution in your answer.

Comment: @entreprenerds For most answers which just link to code off-site, I strongly agree with your comment. However, this question is actually asking for such links to off-SO locations where the SQL can be found, rather than asking directly for the information. Thus, the answer is actually answering the question. It also appears the needed code exceeds the permitted size of an answer (30kB) (even in .zip format). So, basically, in cases like this it's better to just vote or flag the question to be closed as a off-site resource request.