# No usename HR in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have installed oracle 12c in my ubuntu. I use oracle through sqldeveloper and I can successfully connect to user `sys` with my password. I want to be able to use all databases provided by oracle by default. When I try to connect with username `hr` with the same password as in `sys` I get error username not found.

`select * from all_users` doesn't list user `hr`. So I assume the user is not created at all.

- Should it not have been available by default, hr user?

  How can I configure such that I get the access to all `hr` databases?

Comment: I went and followed this tutorial and helped me make the hr connection on Oracle: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maLrgeY0InA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maLrgeY0InA) I made some changes such as the name of the edition, mine is different. Moreover, when he searched for db_home, mine was without the underscore and in c:// so mind that as well. Finally, when tried the connection, on Oracle page, I wrote on the first textbox: HR, the second textbox: system ( which the name I choose as a user name), the last textbox was the password I have chosen, which I decide on while following the tutori

Answer (score 9):

> I have installed oracle 12c in my ubuntu. I assume the user is not created at all.

You have created the **12c database** as a **container**. Now you might be connecting to the **container database** while the **sample schemas** reside in the **pluggable database**.

Oracle 12c has introduced **[multi-tenant architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm)**. There are some mandatory post-installation steps. Please read [**Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/).

The most common misunderstanding is about “`SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA`” usage.

Since we have checked the option to create a single CDB, the “`SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA`” command will always log into **CDB**. Usually developers used to unlock the “`SCOTT/HR`” account directly after logging as `SYSDBA`. But here is the trick :

“SCOTT,HR” and other **sample schemas** are in the **PDB** and not in the **CDB**. So, you need to login as `sysdba` into **PDB**.

For example,

```
sqlplus SYS/password@PDBORCL AS SYSDBA

SQL> ALTER USER scott ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY tiger;

sqlplus scott/tiger@pdborcl

SQL> show user;
USER is "SCOTT"
```

---

**UDPATE** Seems OP has not installed the sample schemas. It could be done manually or via DBCA.

You need to run the **hr_main.sql** script. All scripts necessary to create the Human Resource (HR) schema reside `in $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/human_resources`.

From **[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00005)**,

> **Installing the HR Schema**
>
> All scripts necessary to create the Human Resource (HR) schema reside
>   in $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/human_resources.
>
> You need to call only one script, hr_main.sql, to create all the
>   objects and load the data
>
> Running **hr_main.sql** accomplishes the following tasks:
>
> 1. Removes any previously installed HR schema
> 2. Creates user HR and grants the necessary privileges
> 3. Connects as HR
> 4. Calls the scripts that create and populate the schema objects

Comment: So then I assume I have to complete `Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory` Steps first before I follow your example.

Comment: @PrakashGautam You can complete those steps later, as of now you can unlock the user by connecting to the pluggable database. Just follow the steps I have shown in the demo.

Comment: `sqlplus SYS/<password>@PDBORCL as SYSDBA` gives `ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: @PrakashGautam `PDBORCL` is my pluggable database. You need to use your PDB name. It was just an example. What PDB name did you provide while creating the 12c database? Also, did you add the PDB details to the **tnsnames.ora file**? I guess you must complete the post-installation steps as I have mentioned.

Comment: @PrakashGautam Refer the link I gave for the post installation steps. Please mark it as answered, would help others too.

Comment: I followed the mandatory steps, I can log into sql with `sqlplus SYS/<password>@PDBORCL as SYSDBA` now  `alter user hr account unlock identified by abc` still gives `ORA-01918: user 'HR' does not exist` because `select * from all_users` still doesn't show `hr`

Comment: @PrakashGautam Then most probably you did not install the sample schemas. See the updated answer. Please mark it as answered.

Comment: Unfortunately `hr_main.sql` doesn't exist in the specified directory but `hr_code.sql` does exist. can i download it from here https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/blob/master/human_resources/hr_main.sql

Comment: @PrakashGautam See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452923/where-can-i-get-sql-for-default-oracles-hr-schema you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: The link " Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps" on the answer is pointing to spam. May be that the page doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @LuisMatos Thank you for reporting, I have fixed the URL. Please try now.

Answer (score 2):

you should unlock the `HR` user , connect to SQL and run this command

`ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY password;`

read more about it in the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_connecting.htm#CEGEBAAC)

Comment: OP said, "*select * from all_users doesn't list user hr*" Which means he is looking into the wrong database. Even if the user is locked, it will come in the output in `all_users`. This is the pointer.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I did the select in my database and I didnt find `HR`. i am 11g , anyway maybe yes the user is reading from wrong databsae, we will wait his response

Comment: "*I did the select in my database and I didnt find HR*" Did you install sample schemas? Because as I said, even if you lock the user, you would anyway see it in `SELECT username FROM all_users`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB honestly it is not me who installed the database on the server so I dont have much info about it . its a test database, there is SCOTT and SYSTEM AND SYS. user but not hr

Answer (score 2):

In order to install the sample schemas, you need to follow the instructions from https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas.

Anything from the original Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 demo-folder does not work properly.

Comment: Make sure the pdb is open