# Can't connect sqlplus hr/hr using Oracle Developer days on OVM VIrtualBox

Tags: sql, database, oracle, virtualbox, database-administration

I want to connect my database with `hr database` in my Oracle Developer Days using Oracle VM VirtualBox. When I connect my database using `sqlplus sys/oracle as sysdba`, It's successful and the status is `OPEN`. But, when I open a new tab, and I put `sqlplus hr/hr on [oracle@localhost ~]$`. It doesn't work, and has a warning `ERROR:ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`. After that, I can enter the username, but I can't enter the password. And show a warning again (`ERROR:ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.) I got the `sqlplus hr/hr` from my lecturer and she can logon with it. Do I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the **HR** user created properly?. If not create the user and give all session privileges using the instructions given in this thread :

[No usename HR in Oracle 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731902/no-usename-hr-in-oracle-12c).

To  know that user exists, u may run this query by logging in dba(as u said: `sqlplus sys/oracle as sysdba`)

```
select * from all_users where USERNAME='HR' ;
```

And if you find that  the user exists and  you are not sure about the password, run

```
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK
```

as sysdba to reset the password to *hr* . Try logging in after these steps and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for your help! Now, I can access my hr database! Once again thank you. Finally, I can do my home work. Have a nice day! :D

Comment: @MayaRetnosari by the way HR is not database :), but can be called as "user" or "schema".

Comment: on that VM, all of the passwords are oracle - connect as hr/oracle. of course, changing the password will also work :)

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm sorry, I'm new in Oracle Administration so I dont know much about it. Surely, I'll improve it. Thank you so much for your information,Sir! :