# scott/tiger in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12 c , Release 2 and when starting SQL plus, I wanted to login with scott/tiger but received the following message:

[image: Invalid user]

Invalid user... Any idea how can I make it to work?

Thank you
Sorin

Comment: Use a valid username/password combination.   Isn't the error message obvious?

Comment: I don't think that account is installed by default any more

Comment: oh, I see, that's bad. Are there any scripts to run in order to have the old scott/tiger back and the corresponding tables? what can be done?

Comment: [According to the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/overview.htm#COMSC005) the sample schemas do not include scott any more.

Comment: You may create other sample schema like `HR` for your testing /learning. Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731902/no-usename-hr-in-oracle-12c

Comment: See [**Where is SCOTT user in 12c**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)

Comment: Is there any online sandbox where I can try the HR schema?