# Can't install HR Schema in Oracle Database 12c EE

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

The question is in the title. Gonna say what I have done so far. Firstly, I was here: [Where can I get SQL for default Oracle's "HR" schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452923/where-can-i-get-sql-for-default-oracles-hr-schema), because it turned out I don't have HR user created, and don't even have this schema in demo folder. I downloaded it, installed using offical guide from oracle and... The instalation stops here:

[image]

So I cannot complete steps from here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00004 (starting from point 3...).

After all, when I checked users in **dbs_users** HR still does NOT exist.
What can I do?

Comment: What exactly did you download; where did you put it; and what exactly did you run? And are you working in the root container or a PDB? Is that the entire output you see - or were there errors reported earlier? If you got a version from an earlier release it might not quite work, but without seeing any errors you got it's hard to guess what could need tweaking. Using the current version, and in the right container, would be simpler though...

Comment: I downloaded the same version which is in the link (its about 12c EE, so should be OK) no, there are no errors. I put this in the same folder where it should be (refered to the oracle tutorial) As a conclusion: it is the correct version in the right container

Comment: Container as in root or PDB, not o/s directory. What were you connected to when you ran the script? Or did you install Oracle standalone? The question you linked to has lots of links, so that doesn't tell us what you actually grabbed. Or did you "Install Oracle Database Examples (Companion CD, part of the media kit)" from the 12c doc you also linked to?

Comment: I installed Oracle using this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html
I downloaded the file from the top answer. I was connected to the SYS as SYSDBA. As I told, I did everything like in the oracle tutorials, nothing else.

Comment: According to the tutorial which I used during database instalation I put downloaded schema in: C:\app\OracleHomeUser1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\demo\schema

Comment: If you mean the Google Code link, another answer mentions that won't work. Those files seem to be from 2005, and don't create a new schema - they appear to be set up to install in an existing schema (for ADF?). So you've just created tables in your SYS schema, which is bad. Install the demo scripts from the companion CD, as the docs you linked to said to do. Or via DBCA.

Comment: You're right, I have created tables in SYS. Now, when I downloaded the correct version of HR I cannot install it because cmd tell me that it is already created.

Comment: Installing something you've downloaded from somewhere unofficial, particularly when you don't fully understand what it will do, and especially when running as SYS, is not a very sensible way to proceed. Seriously, follow the instructions in the 12c documentation and install the demo schemas from the companion CD, or through DBCA. You should remove the stuff you already added through those scripts, but very carefully. I'd be tempted, if this is all brand new, to burn it and reinstall everything from scratch - ticking the demo/sample schema boxes this time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instructions here ?

https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas

Comment: It does not make sense to install a software found anywhere in the internet.

Comment: that github project is where we are distributing the sample schemas now, HR, SH, OE, SCOTT, etc.

Comment: all the files you need for creating the user, tables, views, and inserting the data are in the link that Mark provided in his answer.